# Firebase FCM push notification for web

Tags: laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to open an external URL when the user click on FCM push notification on web.
If it is possible can anyone give provide some details on it or any documentation.
Thank you.

I tried firebase documentation and did some research online. There are ways to achieve it in android and ios devices, I think, but could not find anything for web.
I am looking for someone with experience in this or anyone who can provide me with any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [click_action](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support:%7E:text=the%20notification%27s%20icon.-,click_action,-Optional%2C%20string) field which contains the action associated with a user clicking on the notification. Note that for all URL values, HTTPS is required.

Here's a sample for customizing a HTTP v1 message with 'click_action' for Web:

```
{
  "webpush": {

   "notification": {

     "title": "Fish Photos",

     "body": "Thanks for signing up for Fish Photos!",

     "icon": "firebase-logo.png",

     "click_action": "https://example.com/fish_photos"

   }
  }
}
```